# Problem with flash installer

Tags: php, html, flash, wordpress

I HAVE A SITE in wordpress;
the link is www.studium.cl.
When I open in IE, the browser opens a window with a message like a "you need to install adobe flash player blablabla.."

When i install adobe flash player and update the site, this appears again.

How can I fix this, or what is the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

1) Have you closed all your IE windows? (or just reboot your computer to make sure all did close)

2) Do you have admin privileges on your computer, so that Flash could actually install?

Comment: the flash player is install other sites don't have the same problem  the problemS appear when i REBOOT or close the browser , but only appears in IE